# Why is this Django raw SQL query not returning output?

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, django-models, django-orm

I have a raw SQL query that I am trying to run in Django. When I display the RawQuerySet object, it's showing the correct query but it isn't returning any output.

I have tried converting the parameters to string and have tried appending quotes to the parameters but that didn't work.

I have also tried the same query but I hardcoded the parameters. That worked.

I opened the dbshell as well to try and see if the query returns an output. It works fine too.

This is what I ran in my dbshell:

```
select id FROM recommender_item WHERE 
id in (select item_id from 
recommender_item_likes where user_id = 1) 
and color = 'Black';
```

Note, that the below query did not work:

```
select id FROM recommender_item WHERE 
id in (select item_id from 
recommender_item_likes where user_id = 1) 
and color = Black;
```

This is the actual query I want to run:

```
Item.objects.raw('select id FROM recommender_item WHERE 
id in (select item_id from recommender_item_likes where 
user_id = %s) and %s = %s', [request.user.id, user_pref, pref_choice,])
```

This is the same query with hardcoded parameters which is working:

```
Item.objects.raw('select id FROM recommender_item WHERE 
id in (select item_id from recommender_item_likes where user_id = %s) 
and color = "Black"', [request.user.id])
```

The output in my template should be just this list of ids:
1, 64, 437, 1507, 1685

However, right now it just returns []

This is the RawQuerySet object in both cases, respectively:

```
<RawQuerySet: select id FROM recommender_item WHERE 
id in (select item_id from recommender_item_likes where user_id = 1) 
and color = Black>
```

and

```
<RawQuerySet: select id FROM recommender_item WHERE 
id in (select item_id from recommender_item_likes where user_id = 1) 
and color = "Black">
```

Actual SQL query being executed, retrieved from Django debug toolbar:

```
select id FROM recommender_item WHERE 
id in (select item_id from recommender_item_likes where 
user_id = '1') and '''color''' = '''"Black"'''
```

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    #id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4, help_text = 'Unique ID for this particular item')
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    image_URL = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = True, blank = True)
    fit = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    occasion = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    pattern = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    fabric = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    length = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank = True, related_name = 'item_likes')
```

Comment: If you format your code lines to prevent horizontal scrolling, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Sorry! Edited the code to make it easier to read

Comment: I think the output of `RawQuerySet.__repr__` is misleading. If you inspect the actual queries made (using `django.db.connection.queries`), you should find that contrary to RawQuerySet output, string paramters are quoted in the SQL sent to the database. Not sure what this means in your case though; it seems that if your hardcoded query works, so should the parametrized one.

Comment: So I found the actual query being executed through django debug toolbar. It's this:
`select id FROM recommender_item WHERE id in (select item_id from recommender_item_likes where user_id = '1') and '''color''' = '''"Black"''' `
I don't know if this will help though.

Comment: I've tried with Sqlite now, and it works just fine, with string parameters being single-quoted, e.g. `WHERE color = 'black'` (DDT shows triple instead of single quotes though). I'm using Django 2.1.7; maybe there were problems in earlier versions. What is your version?

Comment: My version is the same. Exactly, it works with SQLlite. DDT shows triple quotes too.

Comment: I thought your problem was that it didn't work with Sqlite?

Comment: I mean, it runs in my database shell.

Comment: But it should work in Django as well :). What is `type(pref_choice)`? Did you try passing `str(pref_choice)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should get you all black items liked by the user:

```
Item.objects.filter(likes=request.user, color='Black')
```

Add `.values('id')` if you only need the ids like in the raw query.

But I still find your original problem more interesting. I have no problems issuing raw queries with string parameters to Postgresql. I'll have to try with Sqlite.

BTW, the ORM query highlights that `likes` is a misnomer; `likers` or similar would appear to be a more fitting name.

---

You can expand a dictionary in `filter()`:

```
filter_field = 'color'
filter_string = 'black'
filter_dict = {filter_field: filter_string}
Item.objects.filter(**filter_dict)
```

Comment: I will update the field name to `likers`. It makes sense. How would you supply `color` and `'Black'` as variables though?

Comment: Does this mean I could also do: `filter_field = variable_that_holds_color` and the same for `filter_string`?

Comment: Python doesn't care what the variables are called. You can also run `Item.objects.filter(**{variable_that_holds_field_name: variable_that_holds_color})` directly.

Comment: Thank you! This method works and is definitely more robust than my raw SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a lot of playing around with the shell and the debug toolbar, I have found a somewhat redundant way to achieve this. Create six separate strings:

```
str1 = 'select id FROM recommender_item WHERE id in (select item_id from recommender_item_likes where user_id ='
str2 = str(request.user.id)
str3 = ') and '
str4 = user_pref
str5 = ' = '
str6 = "'"+pref_choice+"'"
q = str1 + str2+ str3 + str4 + str5 + str6
```

Then I pass this variable as such:
`Item.objects.raw(q)`
This gives me the required output.

Given the model changes, you should be able to do this:

`Item.objects.filter(likes=request.user)`

Or

`request.user.item_likes.all()`

Comment: While I don't have the answer you want, this can't be the best way to do it. You should be able to do `f'select ... {str(request.user.id)}) and {user_pref} ...'` to avoid creating multiple strings. Why are you trying to do raw sql? The query looks pretty simple and you should be able to accomplish that with the ORM.

Comment: Yes this is definitely not the best way. I was having trouble constructing the same dynamic query with ORM. Couldn't figure out how to use variables for my field names.

Comment: If you post your models, I can help with that.

Comment: @schillingt Added models.py in the question.

Comment: @schillingt I didn't try fstrings. It's worth a shot.

Comment: Added an ORM suggestion